# Not possible to build ruby project with middleman

Tags: ruby, middleman

I am doing the following:

```
gonvaled@pegasus $ bundle exec 'middleman build --verbose'

...
== Finishing Request: pages/forms/forms.html (0.04s)
      update  build/pages/forms/forms.html
       error  build/javascripts/vendor/jquery.easy-pie-chart

/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:142:in `exec_runtime'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:19:in `eval'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:33:in `call'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:57:in `compile'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.7/lib/tilt/coffee.rb:46:in `evaluate'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.7/lib/tilt/template.rb:77:in `render'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
/home/gonvaled/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
...
```

Lots of things are building properly, but some are failing like this one. I have no idea what is failing: ruby does not mention any specific problem with the input file: the `jquery.easy-pie-chart.coffee` seems ok.

What can I try to debug this? I am new to ruby and middleman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My system had an (spurious) executable called `nodejs` in the `PATH`, and it was preventing the real `nodejs` to run. No messages about this where provided, so it was **really** difficult to find.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install a javascript runtime, like [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer).